# Sinon stub mongoose save to resolve the object which called save

Tags: node.js, testing, mongoose, mocha.js, sinon

I have the following code:

```
const newImage = new Image(...);
newImage.save().then(image => {...})
```

Is there a way to stub the save method for Image to resolve the object which called it? ie. I want `image` in the `then` clause to just be the same as `newImage`

Something like
`sinon.stub(Image.prototype, 'save').resolves(theCallingObject);`

Is this possible? Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `callsFake` to mock the prototype method...

...and if you pass it a normal function (not an arrow function) then `this` will be the instance within the mock function:

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const assert = require('assert');

class Image {
  async save() {
    return 'something else';
  }
}

it('should work', async function() {
  sinon.stub(Image.prototype, 'save').callsFake(
    function() {  // <= normal function
      return Promise.resolve(this);  // <= this is the instance
    }
  );
  const newImage = new Image();
  const result = await newImage.save();
  assert.strictEqual(result, newImage);  // Success!
})
```